# Start service at boot time for android 4.0

Tags: java, android, mobile

I can't not start service when I want to start service at boot time for android 4.0, in android.
My code is below:

```
> public class StartUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{   @Override
>   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         String
> action = intent.getAction();      if
> (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
>           Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, StartAUT_Service.class);
>           Log.i("Broadcast", "startService on boot time:." + myIntent);
>           context.startService(myIntent);         }
>         }    }



> <uses-permission
> android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
>       <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">        
>           <receiver android:name="com.Android.Exercise.StartUpReceiver" android:exported="false">
>               <intent-filter>
>                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
>                   <action android:name="StartInstrument" />
>                   <action android:name="PrintControlName" />              
>               </intent-filter>
>           </receiver>          
>           <service android:enabled="true" android:name="StartAUT_Service">
>               <intent-filter>
>                   <action android:name="com.Android.Exercise.StartAUT_Service" />
>               </intent-filter>
>           </service>
>       </application>
```

And in LogCat show Shutting down VM when i run above project, so my broadcast don't receive action.
Plz help me.!!!
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Mybe this will help you:

> Broadcast Regression Confirmed
>   In a previous post, I cited evidence that the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast will not work out of the box on Android 3.1 until the user uses your app.
>   It’s actually somewhat bigger than that.
>   In the issue that I filed seeking clarification, Ms. Hackborn indicated:
>   Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this state.
>   As a result, when applications are first installed, they are totally ignored by the system until and unless the user manually launches something: clicking on a launcher activity or adding an app widget, most likely.
>   Developers who had been relying upon getting some sort of system broadcast without user intervention will need to adjust their apps for Android 3.1.
>   As I wrote in the previous post:
>   I expect that most apps will be OK. For example, if your boot receiver is there to establish an AlarmManager schedule, you also needed to establish that schedule when the app is first run, so the user does not have to reboot their phone just to set up your alarms. That pattern doesnot change – it’s just that if the user happens to reboot the phone, it will not set up your alarms, until the user runs one of your activities.
>   UPDATE: To clarify the above quote, once the user runs the app for the first time (and does not Force Stop it), everything behaves as before — a reboot will cause BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts to be received and so on. However, if the user installs the app, until and unless they run the app manually, no broadcasts will be received. And if the user force-stops the app, until and unless they run the app manually, no broadcasts will be received.
>   This change is not terribly shocking, as it ratchets up the security another notch by limiting ways malware can run without user knowledge. While it does not offer perfect security — the malware can still install its own copy of an Angry Birds launcher icon and hope users screw up — it is an improvement.

Comment: what is the source for that quote?

Answer (score 1):

In your onResume method of a BroadCastReceiver class put following code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, yourService.class);          
              i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(i);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, i tried, but it still have error,
the first i can not put "super.onReceive" in this code(syntax error).
the second when i copy your code to replace my code it still don't operate.

Comment: @user1266236: I used the above code in my project to start service when device is boot completed. It is working fine for my project